# Windows 11 bootloader screen resolution

Tags: windows-11, bootloader, display-settings

[image]

I'm not having any trouble with the contents or functionality of the Windows 11 boot loader / boot manager; only the screen resolution.
Whenever I reboot my Dell XPS 17 9720, the "Choose and operating system" screen only draws every other line. BIOS looks fine, Windows looks fine, only the boot loader screen does this.
How do I set display properties of the Boot Manager?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to dual boot?

Comment: Yes. I have 2 SSDs, presently Windows 11 is on both, but I'll be installing Linux on the smaller drive tonight. 
I'm not a big fan of grub, (ideally I'd like something like Clover) but since Windows seems so insistent on their boot loader, I'll just use it.

Comment: `since Windows seems so insistent on their boot loader` that doesn't mean you can't use one EFI System Partition and one set of Windows Boot Manager per Windows installation though. IMHO there's literally no reason for one to use WBM to multi-boot Windows installations when they are on separate drives, as it works in such a bad and weird way when being used for that. And you should be able to chainload the WBMs (and grub I suppose) with Clover. (I don't remember for sure, but I don't think you can chainload grub with WBM? Let alone booting Linux kernel directly.)

Comment: I'll take that under consideration; but it still doesn't answer my question as to how to fix the screen resolution in WBM.